# How to display all the image from Azure Blob Storage in table using ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure-storage

As stated in the title. How to display all the image from Azure Blob Storage in table using ASP.NET MVC3?

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [documentation](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) which explains in great details how to achieve different operations with Azure Blob Storage. More specifically checkout the [*How to List the Blobs in a Container*](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#list-blob) and [*How to Download Blobs*](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#download-blobs) sections.

Answer (score 1):

a quick and dirty method can be

```
var accnt = CloudStorageAccount.parse("");//ur accnt string
var client = accnt.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobs = client.GetContainerRefrence(""/*container name*/).ListBlobs();
var urls = new List<string>();
foreach(var blob in blobs)
{
string url = "base host"+blob.uri.AbsoluteUri;
urls.Add(url);
}
//now display it the way you want
```